# Can't figure out NPM, IMGMIN & SVGO to keep/add SVG viewbox

Tags: npm, svg, viewbox, svgo

I'm quite happy with IMGMIN-CLI to optimise images but it removes the viewbox attribute for my SVG files.
I'd also like to add the attribute for the SVG files who don't have it and only have the height / width attributes.

This is the script I run from the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "imgmin": "imagemin --plugin.svgo.removeDimensions=true --plugin.svgo.removeViewbox=false assets/src/img/* --out-dir=assets/dist/img",
    ...
  }
```

And I would run
`npm run imgmin`

Yet, the plugin options don't have any affect.
The SVG files withe viewbox attribute have it removed, and those without don't have it added.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Do I need to declare something somewhere else in the package.json ?

Comment: See the [configuration section in the documentation](https://github.com/svg/svgo)

Comment: This is not helping.

Comment: There's also [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo-viewbox) if you don't understand the information in the links you need to provide somewhat more detailed information (by editing the question) than *this isn't helping*

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you for replying. I have read the docs for imgmin, svgo and all issues related by others that Google could provide.

My understanding is the package to handle images is imgmin and svgo is a plugin of it.

My config is very simple, just running simple scripts `npm run [scss / uglyjs / imgmin]`

I just want is imgmin to not remove the viewbox attribute.
Doc hints that SVGO is required and that I should be able to pass the options in --plugin.[pluginname].[pluginopt]=[value]

Option through scripts work for other packages I don't understand why it doesn't here.